# Simple pitch detection in python

Tags: python, detection, pyaudio, microphone, pitch

I want to perform continuous pitch detection on an audio input from microphone with the help of python code.
When I started googling about this issue I found many complex ways and algorithms. Any of which did not provide an easy way to do it with microphone as source until I came across this library named "pitch" in python.
https://pypi.org/project/pitch/
It is claiming to do pitch detection in 3 easy steps:

```
import pitch
p = pitch.find_pitch('sample.wav')
print('pitch =', p)
```

But after running it with an audio file it is giving same error again and again.
`ValueError: object too deep for desired array`
I have no idea how to fix this error as i am not into numpy or any such modules and also can anybody help me to find an easy method to do it with microphone as audio source

Comment: Welcome to [so] we don't provide debugging services.  You will have to dig into the source for this project.  That is one of the dangers of relying on a project that was last updated 4 years ago.

Comment: Look into scipy fft https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/